# Exported RCP Plugin as jar. file no accsess on CSV file

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I wrote a calender plugin in eclipse with rcp and to input some data in my calender I used a csv. file. When I export my plugin as deployable plugin get I a jar. file. Thats fine, but when I add this jar file to another project have I no access on the csv. and cannot change the data in it. If there is a solution for it?
Greets

Comment: This isn't very clear, but you should not be trying to change data in a plugin jar. If you want something you can change you need to put the data somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you have implemented this.But better you keep the .csv file in the plugin itself.Also If you could explain why you are using the csv file, there could be better options than csv file.
Iff you already have added in the project , Make sure you have checked (selected)the file in Build tab of Maifest.mf file(So that it is exported with the jar.)